# Converting JS to TypeScript: Property 'selectorText' does not exist on type 'CSSRule'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to convert some JS I found here into Typescript

http://bl.ocks.org/Rokotyan/0556f8facbaf344507cdc45dc3622177

Part of the problem is this bit of code

```
// Extract CSS Rules
    var extractedCSSText = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
        var s = document.styleSheets[i];

        try {
            if(!s.cssRules) continue;
        } catch( e ) {
                if(e.name !== 'SecurityError') throw e; // for Firefox
                continue;
            }

        var cssRules = s.cssRules;
        for (var r = 0; r < cssRules.length; r++) {
            if ( contains( cssRules[r].selectorText, selectorTextArr ) )
                extractedCSSText += cssRules[r].cssText;
        }
    }
```

Which I tried to convert to Typescript this way:

```
// Extract CSS Rules
let extractedCSSText = '';
for (let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    const s = <CSSStyleSheet> document.styleSheets[i];

    try {
        if (!s.cssRules) {
            continue;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.name !== 'SecurityError') {
            throw e; // for Firefox
        }
        continue;

    }

    const cssRules = s.cssRules;
    for (let r = 0; r < cssRules.length; r++) {
        if (contains(cssRules[r].selectorText, selectorTextArr)) {
            extractedCSSText += cssRules[r].cssText;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I receive is

Property 'selectorText' does not exist on type 'CSSRule'.

Not sure how to fix that one. Anyone any ideas please?

Thanks, Uwe

Comment: since `CSSRule` is not a type written by yourself you can't really avoid this. A quite bad solution would be smth like this: `if (contains((cssRules[r] as any).selectorText, selectorTextArr)) {...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the CSS spec was defined so that not all [rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule) are necessarily styles.

You have to make sure that the `CSSRule` is a `CSSStyleRule` (as there can be different types of CSS rules that are not styles). It can also be an import rule, keyframe rule, media rule, etc.

Think about a keyframe rule, keyframes don't have selectors so you won't have `selectorText` property on that rule. So, the error is TypeScript doing what it is supposed to do. Make sure you don't access invalid properties.

Try comparing the [CSStyleRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule) properties and [CSSMediaRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSMediaRule) properties. They are different.

Try this:

```
 const cssRules = s.cssRules;
 for (let r = 0; r < cssRules.length; r++) {
    const rule = cssRules[r];
    if (!( rule instanceof CSSStyleRule)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (contains(rule.selectorText, selectorTextArr)) {
        extractedCSSText += rule.cssText;
    }
}
```

Here is an example where simply casting would result in an error being thrown later as `selectorText` can be undefined: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EoBJeM (see console). Avoid casting whenever possible.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I using this code returns this error Type 'CSSRuleList' is not an array type or a string type

Comment: @Uwe Oh, ok, then remove the `for...of` part, I thought it was an array.

Comment: @messerBill Thanks heaps for your initial answer. I still do think it is quite pragmatic, no one says to use ANY everywhere. So thats  cool. However I like Cristy's answer better. It seems cleaner

Comment: so why this deserves the hook?

Comment: @Uwe did you try the second way in my answer? i dont care about this hook but i think the way Cristy gained it for himself was kind of poor, sorry^^ - but seems to be the way to get 10k

Comment: @messerbill I do not care about the points, I just want to make sure if anyone else comes across this problem he finds the correct solution. It's not a good idea to teach anti-patterns to those who are new to something. Casting in `TypeScript` should be avoided whenever possible as you can lose some of the advantages offered by the language. Always keep in mind that types are removed at compile time, so if you cast something and it doesn't actually have that method/property than your code will break at run time.

Comment: My final comment: Liked @messerbill messerbill's answer initially. But Cristy's answers was the more technically sound one.

Comment: @Cristy but not in this case. This will work in 100% of the cases. So it IS a correct answer. I mean....your initial solution produced an error. no more ccomments....i am out bros

Comment: @messerbill It doesn't work in all cases, we don't know how his `contains` implementation is made, or what else he uses the variable for. See my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

so far you have no access to the definitions of the `CSSRule` type you can not really avoid it. To get rid of the error try smth like:

```
if (contains((cssRules[r] as any).selectorText, selectorTextArr)) {...
```

according to Cristys comments this may also work (if it works, use this one):

```
if (contains((cssRules[r] as CSSStyleRule).selectorText, selectorTextArr)) {...
```

**Note:**
You should always try NOT to use the `any` type, but i guess it is ok in this case.

Comment: Thanks heaps, that did the trick. If you don't mind me asking why I 'have no access to the definitions of the CSSRule' yet? Is that a limitation of typescript?

Comment: Please, do not accept this answer, this is wrong and an anti-pattern. Read my answer. If you add "any" to everything you are better without using TypeScript.

Comment: "If you add "any" to everything you are better without using TypeScript" please read my `Note` man...

Comment: @Uwe no but this is not a custom type. that's why i wrote this answer

Comment: @messerbill Yes, but that `cssRules[r]` does not always contain that rule. If you want to cast it, cast it to `CSSStyleRule`, which it is, then it will work. And also, types are removed at compile type, so the best way is to check that the variable is indeed a `CSSStyleRule` before using it.

Comment: Here is an example in which the code breaks https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EoBJeM . It doesn't break with the `instanceOf` check: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpLZZr. And this is a really simple example, of 20 lines of code. If you have a huge project and start using casts like this you will end up with a lot of edge cases throwing errors when they would have been easily caught by TypeScript if used as recommended.

Comment: @messerbill It doesn't matter, all TypeScript code is removed at compile time anyway. Casting does not affect your program in any way, it just affects the TypeScript errors that you get, so by casting you just suppress those errors.

Comment: would you please just be happy with your hook? :D i did neither say `always cast stuff to any` nor i said `there will never be problems with it`. Everything i said was, that in the case of Uwe my solution WILL work, and it does. Thus i guess this conversation is over

Comment: @messerbill No worries. I didn't want to be mean, I just want to make sure the ones who stumble across this answer learn the correct solution. As for TypeScript casting, see here, everything is removed after compilation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20a%20%3D%20undefined%3B%0D%0Aconst%20text%20%3D%20(a%20as%20CSSStyleRule).selectorText

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to debug without more context and a working code example, but I believe you just need to change the assignment on line 4 to be:

```
const s: CSSStyleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
```